# Inequality involving factorial $\binom nk<(en/k)^k$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to prove following inequality:

$$\binom{n}{k}<(en/k)^k$$

I tried Stirling approximation but I could not get anything further. Then I get $$\binom{n}{k}\approx \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}n^n}{2\pi \sqrt{k(n-k)}(n-k)^{n-k}k^k}$$

Comment: You may even be able to get the much sharper $\tbinom{n}{k}<e(n/k)^k$

Comment: @Ross: For $n=10$ and $k=3$, ${n \choose k}=120$ but $e(n/k)^k  < 101$.

Answer (score 12):

$$\binom{n}{k} \left( \frac{k}{en} \right)^k = \frac{n(n-1) \ldots (n-k+1)}{n^k} \frac{k^k}{k! e^k} \leq \frac{k^k}{k! e^k} \text{ and since } e^k = \sum_m \frac{k^m}{m!},\;\;\; \frac{k^k}{k! e^k} < 1.$$